# Node error 'Cannot find module' when running test case

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, testing, nightwatch.js

I'm new to node and nightwatch and I have followed all the Getting Started instructions from Installing node, npm, selenium stand alone, starting the selenium driver, I downloaded the chrome driver as well and have it in the same directory. I have created the conf file and a simple test case js. When I go to run the test case through Node Command Line, I keep getting an error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\x203946\tests'

at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:383:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
at bootstrap_node.js:496:3
```

**Nightwatch.js**

```
{
"src_folders": ["tests"],
"output_folder": "reports",
"custom_commands_path": "",
"custom_assertions_path": "",
"page_objects_path": "pages",
"globals_path": "globals",

"selenium": {
"start_process": true,
"server_path": "node_modules/selenium-standalone/.selenium/selenium-
server/",
"log_path": "./reports",
"host": "127.0.0.1",
"port": 4444,
"cli_args": {
"webdriver.chrome.driver": ""
}
},
"test_settings": {
"default": {
"launch_url": "https://localhost",
"selenium_port": 4444,
"selenium_host": "localhost",
"silent": true,
"desiredCapabilities": {
"browserName": "chrome",
"javascriptEnabled": true,
"acceptSslCerts": true
}
}
}
}
```

**Nightwatch.conf.js**

```
require('babel-core/register');
const fs = require("fs");

module.exports = ((settings) => {
const seleniumFileName =
fs.readdirSync("node_modules/selenium-standalone/.selenium/selenium-
server/");
settings.selenium.server_path += seleniumFileName;
return settings;
})(require("./nightwatch.json"));
```

**Test**

```
module.exports = {
'Does not show the task list if there are no tasks'(client) {
client
.url('http://todomvc.com/examples/react/#/')
.waitForElementVisible('.header h1')
.expect.element('.main').to.not.be.present;
client.end();
},
```

Comment: What's the test file pathname and what command line are you using?

Comment: test file is in e2e/test/testpractice ... and i'm trying to run it on node js command line

Comment: It looks like this is a Node problem not a Nightwatch problem.  There's no evidence in the stack trace that Nightwatch code is running.  I suggest trying Nightwatch directly, then debugging your node setup.  Sample: `node_modules/nightwatch/bin/nightwatch e2e/test/testpractice.js`

Answer (score 0):

You specified "tests" in Nightwatch.js but test file is in "test" directory so a rename of the directory "test" to "tests" would at least fix that. Also, ,I think you should name the config file nightwatch.json